# AWS API Gateway with Lambda Authorizer returns 500 instead of 401

Tags: java, error-handling, aws-api-gateway, lambda-authorizer

I'm building an AWS Lambda Request Authorizer for API Gateway. The stack uses Serverless Framework and the Lambda is in Java.

- When the provided `Authorization` header (API key) is valid, everything works as expected.
- When the `Authorization` header is missing, a 401 response is returned, as expected. In this scenario, API GW doesn't even call the authorizer.
- When an invalid `Authorization` header is provided, the lambda throws a `RuntimeException("Unauthorized")`. I would expect API GW to return a 401 error, but instead a `500 Internal Server` error is received. Not good.

Here's the lambda request handler code:

```java
@Override
public AuthPolicy handleRequest(AuthorizerEvent authorizerEvent, Context context) {
    try {
        return getPolicy(authorizerEvent);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

CloudWatch confirms the RuntimeException is thrown:

```
<last message logged by authorizer>

Unauthorized: java.lang.RuntimeException
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unauthorized
    at com.example.serverless.AuthorizerHandler.handleRequest(AuthorizerHandler.java:30)
    at com.example.serverless.AuthorizerHandler.handleRequest(AuthorizerHandler.java:20)
```

Here's the log when testing the authorizer in the AWS Console, which indicates the error condition was not handled correctly or at all:

```
> Authorizer result body before parsing: {}
> Execution failed due to configuration error: Could not parse policy due to null response or empty JSON.
> AuthorizerConfigurationException
```

What am I doing wrong or not doing right?

Comment: Happens the same to me but in typescript and it doesn't give more information